# Gitlab CI with separate backend and frontend repos

Tags: gitlab, cypress, gitlab-ci, e2e-testing

I've got separate repos for backend and frontend.
Backend is used by another frontends so I cannot merge it with this particular frontend.
Backend is dependant on docker container running mysql.
Frontend depends on backend.

I want to do E2E testing using Cypress and I have everything set up and running locally using docker that runs backend, frontend and mysql.
However this setup does not work properly on Gitlab CI.
I've recreated the environment in `gitlab-ci.yml` but at some point it screams that there is not enough memory and it fails.

How else can I test my app that has frontend and backend on different repos?
Preferably without docker if at all possible since I need a local mysql DB.

Comment: Why can't you just run your Cypress tests on an integration or development environment where the particular code has been deployed from your repositories?

Comment: @SebastianoVierk The CI is pushing everything that passes our current tests to production and we need more tests therefore we have implemented Cypress

Comment: `there is not enough memory and it fails.` If you have a memory problem, it sounds like you need to use a runner with more memory or somehow reduce the memory demand.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your .gitlab-ci.yml so we can help.

Comment: Are you saying your team does not have a an environment other than production?